# I need guidance for developing phonegap apps i am beginner can someone guide me

Tags: cordova

can someone guide me how to create mobile apps for phonegap ,
using jquerymobile online free outsourcing ,
how to work with jquerymobile for phonegap apps generation.

```
            ---------------Thank you in advance-----------------
```

Comment: use google to find tutorials. Use stackoverflow if you want to ask specific code-related question.

Comment: follow http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to decide which mobile platforms you are targeting 
Android, iOS, WP, BB7, BB10, Symbian ...etc

After that you can focus on what you want to learn

ex: if you choose Android, you have to download Eclipse & the Android SDK
    if you choose iOS, you need a Mac with XCode downloaded on it
    .
    .
    etc

After that you can use HTML, CSS, JavaScript and JQueryMobile to create the pages of your app.
and you can use Phonegap API's to use native functions of different mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/) for developing mobile apps using PhoneGap. It supports most of the popular mobile platforms such as iOS, Android and Windows 8. It includes jquery mobile plugin and PhoneGap plugin. All you need to know are just HTML5 and Javascript. You can just write once and deploy to the above platforms. This is a [guide](http://docs.monaca.mobi/en/sampleapp/samples/todo) of developing mobile app using Monaca and PhoneGap.